# How to restore WP 5.4 behaviour where a numeric string could added to each page URL and parsed as "page" in WP 5.5?

Tags: plugin-development, urls, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

In WP 5.4.x, I was able to add a number to the URL for any page, post, etc. (incl. custom post types), which WP interpreted as the 'page' for a multi-page post, even if that page or post didn't actually have multiple pages. I assume that this was some kind of shortcut for /page/12345/

I could, for instance, open /some-page/12345/, even if that page didn't use a "nextpage" tag. The behaviour also worked for custom post types, e.g. WooCommerce products.

I used this behaviour in a custom plug-in where I needed a numeric ID passed (without having to use custom rewrites). In WP 5.5, WP does a 301 redirect via redirect_canonical instead when a post/page doesn't actually have multiple pages. Is there a way to restore that old behaviour in 5.5?

Comment: It seems we are having the same problem! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/372859/193014

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yep, that sounds very much like the same issue. Thanks for alerting me to that topic!

Comment: @EsaJokinen I lack the points to comment on your post, but feel free to point to this one as well.

Comment: See the right column under "Linked": that's a two-way feature! :)